# Maya C++ plugin access to imageFile loaded on the current imagePlane

Tags: c++, plugins, maya

I am writing a Maya C++ plugin that needs to get access to the imageFile that is loaded in the current imagePlane.  I've got the plugin written, and I am able to iterate successfully through the imagePlanes, but I don't know how to get the imageFile that is loaded on the imagePlane.  I have written a plugin that has a callback for the scene being loaded, and I'm that successfully iterateing through the imagePlanes, but how do I proceed from there to get the filename of the image loaded into the imagePlane?  Here's a portion of my code for the sceneLoaded callback:

```
void MayaExtractCalDataPlugin::sceneLoaded( void* clientData )
{
    // Store the pointer to the current class
    MayaExtractCalDataPlugin* crntPlugin = (MayaExtractCalDataPlugin*)clientData;

    // We only enter the callback when isReadingFile() is false, as this indicates that all
    // loading is complete. otherwise we would enter a whole series of callbacks when loading a scene
    // with lots of references in.
    if( !MFileIO::isReadingFile() )
    {
        // Traverse the scene and find image planes 
        // First we need to create an iterator to go through all image planes
        MItDependencyNodes it(MFn::kImagePlane);

        //iterate through all image planes
        while(!it.isDone())
        {

            // Get the imagePlane object
            MStatus status;
            MObject object = it.thisNode(&status);

            ...
         }
    }
}
```

But, now that I have the MObject and I know its an imagePlane, I don't know how to get to the imageFile that is loaded into it.  Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to cast the MObject back to an imagePlane?  What is the data type of the imagePlane?

Comment: That's my problem, I can't find the data type for the imagePlane.  In the Python API, Maya has an imagePlane class.  That is exactly what I need, and I'm sure there is something equivalent in their C++ API, but I can't find it in the documentation.  I must be missing something...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  I just needed to add the following statements after the above code, and I can access all the imagePlane methods and attributes:

```
        // attach a dependency node to the file node
        MFnDependencyNode fn(object);

        // get the attribute for the imageName path
        MPlug imagePath = fn.findPlug("imageName");
```